# Is there a frequency-ranked corpus of Punjabi NAV lemmata?

Tags: corpora, resource-request

I am looking for a list of lexical roots for Punjabi, with frequency information whereby one can get an idea what the 1000 most-frequent words of the language are. I need to exclude case forms etc. hence lemmata; I also need to exclude grammatical particles and interjections, looking for just nouns, adjectives, adverbs and verbs. If there is none, a possible substitute could come from a closely-related language (I don't have a handle on relatedness issues on modern IA). Any script is okay, transliterated is preferred (Gurmukhi is second runner-up), and glossed would be helpful.

Comment: Try your luck with http://tdil-dc.in. But I must caution you that they make you jump through hoops before they let you download anything.

Comment: I'm mildly surprised that they have so little on Punjabi (or Panjabi). Text corpora galore.

Comment: Yeah, the efforts of the Indian government and the local researchers seem really misplaced to me.